# Multiple endpoints to same page

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I'm doing a bit of AB testing, and am looking for a way to point multiple endpoints to the same page in wordpress. My site is using wordpress as it's CMS tool.

```
http://mysite.com/test/link1
http://mysite.com/test/link2
http://mysite.com/test/link3
```

I want the above URL's to point to the about page generated through wordpress

```
http://mysite.com/about
```

The specific use case is to track hits through google analytics. I've tried doing 301 redirects, but searching through referrers for your site doesn't always work. Any idea's?

Comment: A custom permalink rewrite will work for you. Do you want all the urls ending with `link<xyz>` to point to the same `about` page, and always?

Comment: How would you go about doing that? I already have a custom permalink setting in the admin page. And yes, always point to the about page content, but keep the link<xyz> path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay... here's how you add the rule.

```
<?php
    add_action('init', 'add_my_rule');

    function add_my_rule()
    {
        add_rewrite_rule('^test\/link.*$','index.php?pagename=about','top');
    }
?>
```

This rule will ensure that when you visit a url like `http://.../test/link` or `http://.../test/link<xyz>`, you are redirected to the `about` page (please make sure the slug for about page is 'about'). Also, `http://.../test/`, will take you the `test` page and not the `about` page.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: where would I add this rule?

Comment: Add it to `functions.php`. Then go to `Settings > Permalinks`, and just hit the save button.