# Mapping multiple URLs to same page

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, urls

I just came across this page with almost similar requirements as mine

[Multiple endpoints to same page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33250/multiple-endpoints-to-same-page)

i have to achieve same functionality but i also want to pass some parameters to the page where all these URL will be map.
say example

```
http://mysite.com/test/link1
http://mysite.com/test/link2 
http://mysite.com/test/link3
```

i want to map them to same URL

```
http://mysite.com/test/finalDestination
```

along with it i also want to send some other parameters like

1. user email
2. user name

so that i can use them at that page for my custom logic.i know how to do it in JSP/Java where i can send them as a request parameters in POST request and can reterieve them in the final JSP

how i can achieve this is wordpress using php.my prefrences are not to use any query string.

Or is it possible like if i create URL with like

```
http://mysite.com/test/user1
http://mysite.com/test/user2 
http://mysite.com/test/user3
```

where user1 etc can be fetched from the database and we can ensure that they will be unique through the application and mapping these URLs to same end point.
how can i fetch the username in my final page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same answer as the question you referred to (I have answered it). Here's how you would change to pass the arguments:

```
<?php
    add_action('init', 'add_my_rule');

    function add_my_rule()
    {
        global $wp;
        $wp->add_query_var('args');

        add_rewrite_rule('test\/finaldestination\/(.*)','index.php?pagename=about&args=$matches[1]','top');
    }
?>
```

Assuming 'finaldestination' stays the same always, and the pagename (slug) is 'about' (you can change both). Apply your custom template to this page, and on the template, do this:

```
//if you visit http://.../test/finaldestination/name/romeo, then $params will be name/romeo. You can explode this and get the value.
$params = get_query_var('args');
```

After you put this code in your file, just go to `Settings>Permalinks` and hit the save button.
I haven't tried this, but have used something similar in a recent project and I'm sure it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the input basically i have a page with URL's http://localhost/blog/wordpress/author/admin/ where related author post will be shown , i have author.php page where i am using custom query based on some parameters.So all i want is that if i have an author with name "my-author" URL should be http://localhost/blog/wordpress/author/my-author/ which should map with "http://localhost/blog/wordpress/author/admin/" and i can user "my-author" to query my database to fetch his posts.I am not sure how feasible it is.

Comment: i tried your code as follows $wp->add_query_var('args');
  add_rewrite_rule('author/(.*)','index.php?pagename=author&args=$matches[1]','top');  and when i tried to access following URL http://localhost/blog/wordpress/author/my-work/  it giving me 404 error

Comment: Why are you trying to write such a URL? WordPress already has the Author archive url as this. So `http://localhost/blog/author/my-author` always will point to the archive page for `my-author`. Also, One possible reason could be, `author` is a term reserved in WP universe. You should try with some other term instead of author. And, is your page slug `author`?

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by page slug as 'author' just being new to platform make me confused.Thing is these authors will be guest authors with no profile stored or we will not create a user account for them,all we can do is store some author name field in custom section of post and use that for fetching his/her post

Comment: Ohh... if you're new to the platform, then you shouldn't really play around with the URLs. What you're trying to do will take a lot more than a simple URL rewrite rule! One way would be to append the meta fields key (lets say the author name) to the URL and then get the posts which have this meta key.

Comment: That is what i am trying to achieve.my theme already have author.php file so what i am trying to achieve if some one hot URL say  localhost/blog/wordpress/author/aum-kumar i should redirect every URL with patteren  localhost/blog/wordpress/author/ to author.php page where i can use the last parameter as value to search, so in my case "aum-kumar" will be meta field value but till now i am not able to achieve this

Comment: You don't need to write a new rule because what you want already exists. What you can do is, create an account for the guest author with the role as `Contributor`, so that he can write a post, but not publish it. This way, his archive page will be accessible just the way you want, without rewriting any URLs. Read more about WordPress roles: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Comment: agree but there are few authors who just want to send there post and they are done.i poped up with same suggestion but was rejected so i am forced to see such alternative.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1861/discussion-between-rutwick-gangurde-and-user577691)

Comment: @Moderator The system won't let me chat, seems like I don't have 20 reputation on the network!

Comment: i m there on chat you can ping me there if you happens to be there

Comment: I tried to chat already! But for some reason it won't allow me!

Comment: that's really sad,can you point me how i can achieve that?since i am strcuked here some how

Comment: The whole explanation is pretty long, but I'll give some tips. First, do not use the term `author`, use something else while writing the rule. Use the `args` parameter to send an author name to your template file and get and display the posts using this name.

Comment: i tried with writer even something like add_action('init', 'add_my_rule');      
 function add_my_rule()     {    
  global $wp; 
        $wp->add_query_var('args');   
  add_rewrite_rule('writer\/(.*)','index.php?pagename=author&args=$matches[1]','top');     }   but still not working. As a side note i have author.php page as a custom page in my theme directory but still getting 404

Comment: You'll have to change the page slug as well! Edit the page which you've applied the template to, and change the slug to `writer`. Then in this rule, change `pagename=author` to `pagename=writer`. After that, go to `Settings>Permalinks` and just click save.

Comment: i got it what you said.i was not creating a page inside admin pannel but after creating a page and assigning it to my custom tempelate it also showing in menu bar can i ask wordpress not to show that in the menu/submenu.i have no option to upvote your post u have made my day :) thanks for your help so far

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help! You can upvote/accept my answer later when you get enough reputation! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure to add a canonical URL into the header of the duplicate pages, referring to the main instance of the page ... else you'll end up with duplicate content - which is bad for SEO (only matters if these pages are public and indexed).

Also would go for the theme's author.php or permalink %author% in case it's regular WordPress users. You can access the data about like that:

```
$author = get_user_by('slug', $author_name);
$author_id = (int)$author->ID;
$name = $author->first_name.' '.$author->last_name;
```

[WP Codex: get_user_by()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by)

Answer (score -1):

If your words made senses to me correctly, possible solutions are here:

For the first part, you may use [WordPress Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) plugin to satisfy your needs easily.

For the second part, you may use *%author%* for permalink structures. Check out [codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: Can we do this without a plugin as i am not in favour of using plugin when the things can be done with some modification.