# Author Specific URL's in WordPress

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, urls

In continuation of this thread 
[Mapping multiple URLs to same page in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34291/mapping-multiple-urls-to-same-page-in-wordpress)

is there any other way except redirect similar pattern URLs to same page.
Our goal is to provide our guest and other authors there name/email specific URLs so that they can put those links on there website/blogs to encourange there readers to read there guest posts on our platform.

i can easily make sure that for each author who do not have a user profile in our system or don't want to create profile with us should have a unique username which we can associate with his/her posts

e.g
if guest author have unique username is `uniqu-author` URL should be

```
www.mysite.com/author/uniqueauthor
```

now he can place this URL on his/her blog/website and when user came to our system we can redirect reader to a common author page and can extract `uniqueauthor` from URL,issue a query based on this username and come up with all his/her posts.

Any inputs will be much helpful for me to move forward

Thanks in advance

Comment: errmm www.mysite.com/author/nicename is already built-in to wordpress. You don't have to do anything to make it work. see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url.

Comment: If you mean the user does not have a wordpress account and you want a link to display his/her posts then you can using a meta_value query, let me know if thats what you are looking for and i will hit you up.

Comment: @Ijaas: yes that is what exactly i am looking for author will not have a account in our side so all we can store certain custom attribute in his/her post and we will make sure it will be unique for each author and we want to use them for our query, i looked at get_author_posts its a good function but sadly does not fit in to my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go:

```
add_action('init', 'wp_new_flush_rewrite_rules'); //Run this action only ONCE if not you are looking at 2 extra db queries on every page load so dont forget to comment it out
function wp_new_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite; 
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'new_rewrite_rules');
function new_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {

    $post_type = 'post';

    $new_rules = array(

        'writer/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type='.$post_type.'&meta_key=writer&meta_value='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&paged='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(2),
        'writer/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type='.$post_type.'&meta_key=writer&meta_value='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),

    );

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;   
    return $wp_rewrite;

}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
function add_query_vars( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'meta_key';
    $vars[] = 'meta_value';
    return $vars;
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'template_redirect_intercept');
function template_redirect_intercept(){

    global $wp_query;

    if ( $wp_query->get('writer') && file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . '/author.php' ) ){
        $wp_query->is_404 = ''; $wp_query->is_archive = 1; $wp_query->is_post_type_archive = 1; // This is to prevent 404 errors on page 2,3,4 if posts for that page dont exist.
        include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/author.php' );
        exit;
    }

}
```

it is written to search for the 'writer' meta value of a post and display the author.php template.

the url will look like mysite.com/writer/WRITERNAME/
pagination also works so mysite.com/writer/WRITERNAME/page/2/ will work without an issue.

Comment: i tried your code but its not working.Sorry i am just trying my hands with php and wordpress.here is what i did. i added your code to the function.php file under theme directory,in one of the post i added following "custom field" fieldname="writer" fieldvalue="test-url" now i hit the following URL http://localhost/blog/wordpress/writer/test-url/ but its redirecing me to home page.Can you point what i am doing wrong as i have also author.php file in place

Comment: when i looked at the log apache one i found following entries  require_once() F:\\wamp\\www\\blog\\wordpress\\wp-config.php:90, referer: http://localhost/blog/wordpress/writer/test-url/

Comment: if you could send me an email at ijaas@dex-labs.com with some sort of IM contact details it would be a lot easier for me to help you out. Thanks.