# Creating author Specific page URL

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting

My Question is almost similar to [author-specific-urls-in-wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34476/author-specific-urls-in-wordpress) and [mapping-multiple-urls-to-same-page-in-wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34291/mapping-multiple-urls-to-same-page-in-wordpress/34485#34485). And i have followed the following steps

1. Created a custom page (writer.php)
2. Associated that page from dashboard

since all the writer are not being registered with word-press so WP build in author functionality is not of any help for me.
So i created a custom URL something like

```
$author_page_url = home_url( '/' );
$author_page_url .='writer/'.$author_id[0];
```

where `author_id` is being fetched from the database.i have following entry in my function.php

```
add_action('init', 'add_my_rule');      
    function add_my_rule()     {    
            global $wp; 
            $wp->add_query_var('args');   
            add_rewrite_rule('writer\/(.*)','index.php?pagename=writer&  
                         args=$matches[1]','top'); 
                }
```

and on writer.php i am doing something like

```
$params = get_query_var('args'); 
            $ppp = get_option('posts_per_page');
            if (!is_paged()) {
                    $custom_offset = 0;
            } else {
                $custom_offset = $ppp*($paged-1);   
            }
            $args = array( 'meta_key' => 'writer', 'meta_value' => $params 
                       ,'numberposts' => $ppp,'offset' => $custom_offset);
            $authorposts=get_posts($args);
```

My problem is when i am hitting the following URL `http://localhost/blog/wordpress/writer/umesh-awasthi` WP is giving me 404 Error.while the URL `http://localhost/blog/wordpress/writer/` is working perfectly fine.

Initialy when i developed this, it was working fine and now i have no clue what is going wrong.
Can any one help me to debug the problem.Thanks in advance.

**Update**

My initial doubt is that the rewrite rule is not working but not sure why

Comment: Did you flush your rewrite rules? (Go to settings > permalinks)

Comment: @RobVermeer  you mean hitting the save button? if this is the case yes i already did it many times  but it did not worked :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works if I delete the newline.

So this should work:

```
function add_my_rule() {    
    add_rewrite_tag("%args%", '([^/]*)', 'args=');
    add_rewrite_rule('writer/([^/]*)','index.php?pagename=writer&args=$matches[1]','top'); 
}
add_action('init', 'add_my_rule');
```

Comment: no, its still giving me 404.i even lush your rewrite rules by (settings > permalinks)

Comment: Strange... If you change the rewriterule to `add_rewrite_rule('writer/([^/]*)','index.php?pagename=writer&args=$matches[1]','top'); `

Comment: still same problem 404. I am using `WAMP` server.

Comment: I installed a fresh WP install on my wamp, added the code and page (writer) and then if I go to /writer/umesh-awasthi/ it works. So can you try this in a default theme, like twenty-eleven?

Comment: strange..will try that, but i believe if this is working for you should work for me also

Comment: Yeah, but maybe it is some other piece of code in your theme. So testing only that piece of code in the default theme is often an easy test.

Comment: i added these extra lines in y function `global $wp_rewrite;
 $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` and it started working.Really strange not sure should i keep them or remove

Comment: That's strange, cause going to the permalinks settings should flush your rules already. Removing `global $wp_rewrite; $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` should not break things, cause the rules are already flushed. Flushing them on every request is not something you would like.