# How to define a callback for an URI?

Tags: url-rewriting, callbacks

I have a function in functions.php like so:

```
function myplugin_mycallback($id) {
  // do something
}
```

I want this function called whenever a URL like myplugin/mycallback/xxx is accessed.

How/where do I define this path so it doesn't generate a 404?

Comment: You'll need a url rewrite.

Comment: Gotcha. Is hook_rewrite_rules the best place for that?

Comment: Check my answer over here... should give you an idea... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34291/mapping-multiple-urls-to-same-page-in-wordpress/34485#34485

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`add_feed( $url, $callback )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_feed). Despite its name it sends a `text/html` Content-Type.

Basic example:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_50841_register_extra_page' );

function wpse_50841_register_extra_page()
{
    add_feed( 'wpse50841', 'wpse_50841_callback' );
}

function wpse_50841_callback()
{
    print '<p>It works!</p>';
}
```

Visit the permalink settings page once to refresh the rewrite cache, and go to `example.com/wpse50841/` or `example.com/?feed=wpse50841` to see your code in action.