# Setting up a virtual subdirectory to display identical content as root directory

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, htaccess, directory

We have a standard Wordpress installation being used as a CMS. We're using standard pages with basic permalinks (e.g., /page/ or /parent/page/).

We'd like to have that exact same content mapped to a virtual subdirectory as well (e.g., /vip/page/ or /vip/parent/page/).

Now, obviously, I could duplicate the pages in Wordpress, but that's too much of a pain to manage. The content in both versions would be identical, but we'd do a few minor things in the Wordpress template to display things slightly differently based on the detected URL.

I'm fairly certain there should be a way to do this using .htaccess, but I can't find the right combination of Google keywords to find my answer. Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: It's also worth noting that I'm aware of the potential penalties for SEO, but I plan on supplying canonical meta tags for Google's purposes. The separate URL system is predominantly for marketing and tracking purposes only.

Comment: [Does this answer help](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34291/mapping-multiple-urls-to-same-page)?

Comment: Actually, yes. The short answer is `add_rewrite_rule('vip/?$','index.php?page_id=6','top');` does work, but I basically have to have a line per page right now. I could probably refactor that to make it more flexible, but this works for the pinch I'm in. If you submit that as an answer, I'd gladly vote for that as the correct one.