# map multiple URLs to display home page without changing URL displayed in browser's location bar

Tags: url-rewriting

This is similar to [multiple endpoints to same page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33250/multiple-endpoints-to-same-page), but the fact that I'm trying to display the home page rather than some sub-page within the site seems to be throwing things off

I have 3 URLs:

```
www.mysite.com/test/link1
www.mysite.com/test/link2
www.mysite.com/test/link3
```

I would like for requests to all 3 to display the page at www.mysite.com. Additionally, I need for the URL displayed in the browser's location bar to remain unchanged.

Currently, I'm using:

```
<?php
    add_action('init', 'add_my_rule');

    function add_my_rule()
    {
        add_rewrite_rule('^test\/link.*$','index.php','top');
    }
?>
```

Requesting any of the above URLs does display the page at `www.mysite.com` as expected, **BUT** the URL displayed in the browser's location bar also changes to `www.mysite.com` instead of remaining unchanged and keeping the URL of the initial request.

I'm guessing it has something to do with my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

but I'm not really sure what it could be.

Comment: Is your front page a static page or the posts page?

Comment: It is a Static page.

Comment: Then [this is your answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/184179/4771).

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thx!